# "fork disable" disables other fork although its wrapped in fork-join

Tags: verification, system-verilog

i have a problem with "fork disable" that disables other processes. i already wrapped it inside fork join".is there another solution for that? that's the problematic code inside the agent:

```
fork
    begin
     fork 
       begin
          this.collect_tr();
          ap.write(collected_trans);
          collected_trans.i2c_trans_cg.sample();
       end
       begin
          wait (this.flow_is_ok == 1'b0);
       end
     join_any;
     disable fork;
    end
    join
```

the "disable" is preventing another fork in my reference model from happening. (when i remove the disable fork of the agent, the fork in the RM does happen. i played around with some printing and it happens on the same clock)

Comment: You never showed us where the "another fork" was fork'ed from.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem. the "other fork" in the reference model that was disabled, was called from the ap write() function implementation in the reference model. since the ap.write() in the agent was disabled, the write() in the reference model is disabled as well. so i just moved the ap.write() outside of the fork.

```
fork
  begin
    fork 
      begin
        this.collect_tr();
        //ap.write(collected_trans);
        //collected_trans.i2c_trans_cg.sample();
      end
      begin
        wait (this.flow_is_ok == 1'b0);
      end
    join_any;
    disable fork;
  end
join
if(this.flow_is_ok == 1'b1)begin
  ap.write(collected_trans);
  collected_trans.i2c_trans_cg.sample();
end
```

`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable an inner fork, you can name the fork blocks and then disable the named block.

Example:

```
fork: outer
  begin
    #10;
    $display($stime, " outer");
  end

  begin
    fork: inner

      begin
        #5;
        $display($stime, " inner 1");
      end

      begin
        #7;
        $display($stime, " inner 2");
      end

    join_any
    disable inner;
  end
join
```

Output:

```
#          5 inner 1
#         10 outer
```

Full runnable example here: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/26d

Comment: This is a bad practice in class based code because the named block (in this case `inner`) is not specific to a class object.

Comment: I agree this can be dangerous with class-based code, but it does answer the OP's question. Is there an alternative that is not as bad of a practice?

Comment: It doesn't answer the original question because it was not asked correctly. You could write your code as
`fork: outer
  begin
    #10;
    $display($stime, " outer");
  end
  fork begin
    fork: inner

      begin
        #5;
        $display($stime, " inner 1");
      end

      begin
        #7;
        $display($stime, " inner 2");
      end

    join_any
    disable fork; //inner
  end join
join`